# browsermob-proxy-rb wit watir/selenium

Tags: ruby, rubygems, selenium-webdriver, watir-webdriver

I'm searching to figure out what to put on the the next line of code on https://github.com/jarib/browsermob-proxy-rb:

```
server = BrowserMob::Proxy::Server.new("/path/to/download/browsermob-proxy")
```

so what to put on /path/to/download/browsermob-proxy and where is it or how to download and put it there? I'm on windows xp trying to setup and make har file.

Answer (score 0):

path can be found in folder of gems and in my case it is:

```
'C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/browsermob-proxy-0.1.3/lib/browsermob-proxy.rb'
```

Answer (score 0):

The Ruby Browsermob gem is a wrapper to control the proxy written in Java from your Ruby script.

You need to provide the path to the proxy executable, so that the gem can start the server for you.

Example:

```rb
browsermob_bin = "/path/to/browsermob-proxy-2.1.4/bin/browsermob-proxy"
server = BrowserMob::Proxy::Server.new browsermob_bin
server.start
```

You can dowload the proxy binary from here: https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy/releases